# Why my kotlin suspend function don't throw error? And continue to nextline?

Tags: android, kotlin, suspend

This is my code in my viewModel which calls the function.

```
viewModelScope.launch {
        resource.postValue(Resource.loading(true))
        try {
            localRepository.insertFile(fileEntity)
///This lines throw exeption
            messageRepository.sendMessageWithMediaAudio(message, mediaUri,        duration)
///But still continue to this line and don't catch the error
            resource.postValue(Resource.success(true))
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            Timber.e(exception)
            resource.postValue(
                Resource.error(exception, exception.message!!)
            )
        }
    }
```

I want to catch the error but it wont go to catch.

This is the suspend function

```
  suspend fun sendMessageWithMediaAudio(message: Message, uri: Uri, duration: Long) =
    withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        applicationScope.launch{Body}.join()
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of this line:

```kotlin
applicationScope.launch { 
    Body 
}
```

You are launching a new coroutine in a different coroutine scope. `sendMessageWithMediaAudio` returns before the `Body` completes. If you want to wait until `sendMessageWithMediaAudio` completes (which probably is what you want looking at the call to `.join()`), don't use `applicationScope`, just launch the new coroutine in the scope provided by `withContext`.

Also, launching a new coroutine and immediately waiting for it to complete (`.join()`) isn't of any use. You can simply put the `Body` directly inside `withContext`.

```kotlin
suspend fun sendMessageWithMediaAudio(message: Message, uri: Uri, duration: Long) {
    withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        Body
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried, but still don't get any error in view model and still calling the next line after

Comment: That shouldn't happen. I tried to reproduce this in this [example](https://pl.kotl.in/n8q2_sFOm). In this case, the exception is caught. Have you written something different?

Comment: i have a try catch also in my sendMessageWithAudio function. Does that gives the problem?

Comment: Yeah, if you have try catch there (placed properly) it will catch the exception and exception won't be propagated further

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the info